# Tranpose words either side of underscore in emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there some means of transposing words separated by a `_` (underscore) in Emacs?

<kbd>M-t</kbd> doesn't do it, I think it's looking for a whitespace separator.

This would be handy when dealing with C-style variable/function names, e.g. `my_var`, `my_other_var`, `a_really_complex_function`.

Another annoyance is <kbd>C-M-t</kbd> opening a new terminal in Ubuntu rather than performing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `transpose_sexps`.

Comment: Your second annoyance is really a separate question, and may be better suited to http://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `subword-mode` or `global-subword-mode`. That should give you the behaviour you're looking for.

This can be done interactively using `M-x` or it can be added to your Emacs configuration.

For example:

```lisp
;; Enable for C-mode
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (subword-mode 1))

;; Enable by default
(global-subword-mode 1)
```

Comment: I notice .c files default to C/l (major) mode for me in emacs - would that c-mode-hook affect only that major mode? in which case that would be ideal.

Comment: No, it will not effect derived modes, only c-mode. c-mode-common-hook is the one that will run in all derived modes.

Comment: @JordonBiondo, I stand corrected. The [Emacs manual agrees with you](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/CC-Hooks.html).